# How would a textView change its frame without calling setFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently debugging an issue in our app with a UITextView getting its last few lines cut off. The `UITextView` is inside of a collectionView cell that allows itself to be collapsed. I'm trying to catch the execution of the hiding of the text when its frame changes, so I set a symbolic breakpoint on `-[UITextView setFrame:]`, and this will pause a ton of times during setup of the collectionView as expected.

However, when I hit the minimize button, the textView's frame somehow changes it's origin and height, but I never get a call to `setFrame:` (or at least my breakpoint never gets hit.) I also never get a call to `setFrame:` when I expand it, when again the origin and height changes.

The only code I call which manipulates the textView directly is hiding and unhiding it. After hiding, I then call the following:

```
- (void)updateCollection {
[self.collection performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
[self.amountCell updateTable];
[self.collection setNeedsLayout];
[self.collection layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

The `amountCell` is unrelated to the cell I'm dealing with, so I don't think it has anything to do with this. Somehow, between hiding the `UITextView` and then calling a few updating methods on the collectionView, the frame changes without actaully calling `setFrame:`. How is this possible? How else could the frame be manipulated? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Does `setBounds:` or `setCenter:` get called?

Comment: Perfect! Did not at all think about `setBounds:`. For some reason I thought that would eventually call `setFrame:`. Now if I could just find out why this is setting my bounds so weirdly.... BTW, if you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

One place you might look is in the collection view's `-layoutSubviews` method, which will be called by the framework whenever it determines that the layout needs to be updated, which you are hinting that it does when you invoke `-setNeedsLayout` and `-layoutIfNeeded`.  It's an often-overlooked "hidden" influencer, especially with later versions of iOS shifting focus more to view controllers and away from views.